# Stratified K-fold splitting with replicas in Python

Tags: python, cross-validation

I have a data set that consists of several test systems for which testing has been repeated in replicate for each system.

The total number of replicas is constant (balanced) over all systems, but each replica may contain a different number of total observations.

I would like to use cross validation to split the data into training and testing sets such that:

1. Each system in represented in both testing and training set
2. The training set will contain all but 1 replica for each system while the testing set contains the remaining replica for each system
3. The percentage of observations from each system in the testing set matches the percentage of observations from each system in the training set

I was hoping to use sci-kit learn's StratifiedKFold function, but it does not seem to get me what I need.

For instance, using this example labeling data:

```
labels=np.concatenate([['Sys1']*35,['Sys2']*33,['Sys3']*36])
reps=np.concatenate([
    np.concatenate([
        ['Rep_0']*10,['Rep_1']*10,['Rep_2']*5,['Rep_3']*10]),
    np.concatenate([
        ['Rep_0']*8,['Rep_1']*10,['Rep_2']*10,['Rep_3']*5]),
    np.concatenate([
        ['Rep_0']*10,['Rep_1']*7,['Rep_2']*9,['Rep_3']*10])
])
frames=np.concatenate([
    np.concatenate([
        np.arange(10),np.arange(10),np.arange(5),np.arange(10)]),
    np.concatenate([
        np.arange(8),np.arange(10),np.arange(10),np.arange(5)]),
    np.concatenate([
        np.arange(10),np.arange(7),np.arange(9),np.arange(10)])
])
sampleKeys=np.array(map(lambda x,y: '.'.join([x,y]),
               labels,
               reps))
```

I tried splitting over labels:

```
cvSplitter=skl.model_selection.StratifiedKFold(n_splits=4)
iSplit=0
for train_indices, test_indices in cvSplitter.split(labels,labels):
    print '--- split %g ---'%iSplit
    print 'TRAIN:'
    for sample in np.array([np.unique(sampleKeys[train_indices],return_counts=True)[0],
           np.unique(sampleKeys[train_indices],return_counts=True)[1]]).T:
        print sample

    print 'TEST:'
    for sample in np.array([np.unique(sampleKeys[test_indices],return_counts=True)[0],
           np.unique(sampleKeys[test_indices],return_counts=True)[1]]).T:
        print sample

    iSplit=iSplit+1
```

but, while the result contains equal percentages of observations from each system in training versus testing, the training sets include all replicas for some or all systems whereas I want the training set to include all but one replica while the testing set contains the missing replica.

```
--- split 0 ---
TRAIN:
['Sys1.Rep_0' '1']
['Sys1.Rep_1' '10']
['Sys1.Rep_2' '5']
['Sys1.Rep_3' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_1' '9']
['Sys2.Rep_2' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_3' '5']
['Sys3.Rep_0' '1']
['Sys3.Rep_1' '7']
['Sys3.Rep_2' '9']
['Sys3.Rep_3' '10']
TEST:
['Sys1.Rep_0' '9']
['Sys2.Rep_0' '8']
['Sys2.Rep_1' '1']
['Sys3.Rep_0' '9']
--- split 1 ---
TRAIN:
['Sys1.Rep_0' '9']
['Sys1.Rep_1' '2']
['Sys1.Rep_2' '5']
['Sys1.Rep_3' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_0' '8']
['Sys2.Rep_1' '2']
['Sys2.Rep_2' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_3' '5']
['Sys3.Rep_0' '9']
['Sys3.Rep_2' '8']
['Sys3.Rep_3' '10']
TEST:
['Sys1.Rep_0' '1']
['Sys1.Rep_1' '8']
['Sys2.Rep_1' '8']
['Sys3.Rep_0' '1']
['Sys3.Rep_1' '7']
['Sys3.Rep_2' '1']
--- split 2 ---
TRAIN:
['Sys1.Rep_0' '10']
['Sys1.Rep_1' '8']
['Sys1.Rep_3' '8']
['Sys2.Rep_0' '8']
['Sys2.Rep_1' '9']
['Sys2.Rep_2' '3']
['Sys2.Rep_3' '5']
['Sys3.Rep_0' '10']
['Sys3.Rep_1' '7']
['Sys3.Rep_2' '1']
['Sys3.Rep_3' '9']
TEST:
['Sys1.Rep_1' '2']
['Sys1.Rep_2' '5']
['Sys1.Rep_3' '2']
['Sys2.Rep_1' '1']
['Sys2.Rep_2' '7']
['Sys3.Rep_2' '8']
['Sys3.Rep_3' '1']
--- split 3 ---
TRAIN:
['Sys1.Rep_0' '10']
['Sys1.Rep_1' '10']
['Sys1.Rep_2' '5']
['Sys1.Rep_3' '2']
['Sys2.Rep_0' '8']
['Sys2.Rep_1' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_2' '7']
['Sys3.Rep_0' '10']
['Sys3.Rep_1' '7']
['Sys3.Rep_2' '9']
['Sys3.Rep_3' '1']
TEST:
['Sys1.Rep_3' '8']
['Sys2.Rep_2' '3']
['Sys2.Rep_3' '5']
['Sys3.Rep_3' '9']
1
​
```

If I split over 'reps' instead, I end up with some systems being left out of the testing and / or training data.

Answer (score 0):

Thus far I have managed to produce a function that will split over reps, ensuring that the training data contains all but one rep for each system and the test data contains the rep that was not included in the training set (the function just spits back needed indices so far)... I am a bit puzzled as to how to ensure that the data is stratified w.r.t number of samples from each system.

using original test example

```
labels=np.concatenate([['Sys1']*35,['Sys2']*33,['Sys3']*36])
reps=np.concatenate([
    np.concatenate([
        ['Rep_0']*10,['Rep_1']*10,['Rep_2']*5,['Rep_3']*10]),
    np.concatenate([
        ['Rep_0']*8,['Rep_1']*10,['Rep_2']*10,['Rep_3']*5]),
    np.concatenate([
        ['Rep_0']*10,['Rep_1']*7,['Rep_2']*9,['Rep_3']*10])
])
frames=np.concatenate([
    np.concatenate([
        np.arange(10),np.arange(10),np.arange(5),np.arange(10)]),
    np.concatenate([
        np.arange(8),np.arange(10),np.arange(10),np.arange(5)]),
    np.concatenate([
        np.arange(10),np.arange(7),np.arange(9),np.arange(10)])
])
sampleKeys=np.array(map(lambda x,y: '.'.join([x,y]),
               labels,
               reps))
```

and splitting function:

```
def stratifiedReplicaSplit(sysLabels,repLabels,nSplits):
    sampleLabels=map(lambda x,y: '.'.join([str(x),str(y)]),
                     sysLabels,repLabels)
    nSysLabels=len(np.unique(sysLabels))
    nRepLabels=len(np.unique(repLabels))

    outInds=[]

    sysTypes=np.sort(np.unique(sysLabels))
    repTypes=np.sort(np.unique(repLabels))
    #generate a list of all possible combinations for having a single
    #rep from each system.
    #we will shamelessly hack np.meshgrid to achieve this.
    #we then sample nSplits entries from this list (without replacement)
    tempRepSets=[np.arange(nRepLabels)]*nSysLabels
    comboSetGrids=np.array([np.array(tempGrid.flat) for tempGrid in np.meshgrid(*tempRepSets)])
    #we can now generate a unique split by sampling from the total set of all
    #possible combo sets (without replacement)
    comboInds=np.random.choice(comboSetGrids.shape[1],nSplits,replace=False)
    combosArray=comboSetGrids[:,comboInds].T
    print 'sysTypes',
    print sysTypes
    print 'repTypes',
    print repTypes
    print combosArray
    #print 'sample labels'
    #print sampleLabels
    for iSplit in np.arange(nSplits):
        comboSet=combosArray[iSplit].flatten()
        print comboSet
        outInds.append(
            [np.argwhere(
                np.product(
                    [map(lambda x: x!='%s.%s'%(
                                sysTypes[iEntry],
                                repTypes[entry]),
                           sampleLabels) \
                             for iEntry,entry in enumerate(comboSet)],
                    axis=0)).flatten(),
            np.argwhere(
                np.sum(
                    [map(lambda x: x=='%s.%s'%(
                                sysTypes[iEntry],
                                repTypes[entry]),
                           sampleLabels) \
                             for iEntry,entry in enumerate(comboSet)],
                    axis=0)>0).flatten()])
    return outInds
```

I then run:

```
cvSplitter=stratifiedReplicaSplit
iSplit=0
for train_indices, test_indices in cvSplitter(labels,reps,4):
    print '--- split %g ---'%iSplit
    print 'TRAIN:'
    for sample in np.array([np.unique(sampleKeys[train_indices],return_counts=True)[0],
           np.unique(sampleKeys[train_indices],return_counts=True)[1]]).T:
        print sample

    print 'TEST:'
    for sample in np.array([np.unique(sampleKeys[test_indices],return_counts=True)[0],
           np.unique(sampleKeys[test_indices],return_counts=True)[1]]).T:
        print sample

    iSplit=iSplit+1
```

and obtain
sysTypes ['Sys1' 'Sys2' 'Sys3']

```
repTypes ['Rep_0' 'Rep_1' 'Rep_2' 'Rep_3']
[[2 0 1]
 [0 1 2]
 [3 0 1]
 [0 2 3]]
[2 0 1]
[0 1 2]
[3 0 1]
[0 2 3]
--- split 0 ---
TRAIN:
['Sys1.Rep_0' '10']
['Sys1.Rep_1' '10']
['Sys1.Rep_3' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_1' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_2' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_3' '5']
['Sys3.Rep_0' '10']
['Sys3.Rep_2' '9']
['Sys3.Rep_3' '10']
TEST:
['Sys1.Rep_2' '5']
['Sys2.Rep_0' '8']
['Sys3.Rep_1' '7']
--- split 1 ---
TRAIN:
['Sys1.Rep_1' '10']
['Sys1.Rep_2' '5']
['Sys1.Rep_3' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_0' '8']
['Sys2.Rep_2' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_3' '5']
['Sys3.Rep_0' '10']
['Sys3.Rep_1' '7']
['Sys3.Rep_3' '10']
TEST:
['Sys1.Rep_0' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_1' '10']
['Sys3.Rep_2' '9']
--- split 2 ---
TRAIN:
['Sys1.Rep_0' '10']
['Sys1.Rep_1' '10']
['Sys1.Rep_2' '5']
['Sys2.Rep_1' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_2' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_3' '5']
['Sys3.Rep_0' '10']
['Sys3.Rep_2' '9']
['Sys3.Rep_3' '10']
TEST:
['Sys1.Rep_3' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_0' '8']
['Sys3.Rep_1' '7']
--- split 3 ---
TRAIN:
['Sys1.Rep_1' '10']
['Sys1.Rep_2' '5']
['Sys1.Rep_3' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_0' '8']
['Sys2.Rep_1' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_3' '5']
['Sys3.Rep_0' '10']
['Sys3.Rep_1' '7']
['Sys3.Rep_2' '9']
TEST:
['Sys1.Rep_0' '10']
['Sys2.Rep_2' '10']
['Sys3.Rep_3' '10']
```

... So, in essence, I have reproduced a variant of 'LeaveOneGroupOut' splitting (more specifically, leave one combination of target-group pairs out).
This is okay, but the relative sample size for each system in the test data is not proportional to the relative sample size for that system in the training data... I need to stratify / balance somehow. E.g. the percentage of samples for a system in the training set should match its percentage of samples in the testing set...